# How to trigger an event after n seconds inside a react useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a reactJS app that calls an API using a hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch("/api/r/" + sid);
        const result = await res.json();
        setResult(result);
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData().catch(console.error);
}, [sid]);
```

sometimes this API takes a long time to return all the data, in there a way to trigger an event after n seconds if I didn't receive the data yet, so I can show a message to the user?

Comment: you can add timeout? or you can only show message and still wait for response?

Comment: What message do you want to show if you get delayed to get a response from API?

Comment: yes I would like to show a message after let's say 30s

Comment: You can add a loader component, need to render the loader component while fetching the data from API, once you get a response from API, stop rendering loader component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show after a specific amount of time, you can you setTimeout inside the useEffect. Like this:

> Edit: Remember to remove/clean your timeout on a useEffect cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch("/api/r/" + sid);
        const result = await res.json();
        setResult(result);
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData().catch(console.error);

   // I am using 1 sec as an example
    const messageTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{
       showMessage();
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearTimeout(messageTimeout);

}, [sid]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout()` to delay some actions an example would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch("/api/r/" + sid);
        const result = await res.json();
        setResult(result);
        setIsLoading(false);

        setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('I will appear after 1000ms');
        }, 1000);
    };

    fetchData().catch(console.error);
}, [sid]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a timer to cache `setTimeout` and then when request not back to
show message or back to cancel. like:

```js
  const timer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      if(timer.current) clearTimeout(timer.current)
      timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('request slow, please be paint!')
      }, 20000)

      const res = await fetch('/api/r/' + sid);
      const result = await res.json();

      clearTimeout(timer.current)
      
      setResult(result);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
   
    fetchData();
  }, [sid]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom hook something like below

```
const useFetch(() => {
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
 const [error, setError] = useState()
 const [data, setData] = useState()
 // use api call here and set the above states
 return {isLoading, error, setData};
})
```

or you can use https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery